# Redirect to SSL except when URL matches a certain criteria

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

This is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]


AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_CGI_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    ^([0-9A-Za-z]{12})(\/.+|\.html?|$)   /cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=download1&id=$1&fname=$2 [L]
RewriteRule    ^ot:(.*)             /cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=download1&otid=$1 [L,B]
```

Currently it is redirecting everything to SSL. However I want it so that when the filename fulfills this criteria

```
RewriteRule    ^([0-9A-Za-z]{12})(\/.+|\.html?|$)   /cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=download1&id=$1&fname=$2 [L]
```

It needs to only allow non-SSL

I've googled and googled but I can't figure out how to do this.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In the rule that does the redirect, just add an exclusion condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([0-9A-Za-z]{12})(\/.+|\.html?|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or you can combine it with the rule's pattern:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^([0-9A-Za-z]{12})(\/.+|\.html?|$) https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

---

EDIT:

To redirect SSL requests for that pattern to non SSL add this right below the other redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]{12})(\/.+|\.html?|$) https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Almost there. I need it so it can't use SSL on that exclusion. If its using SSL it would need to redirect to non-SSL. But only for that criteria.